# CRMService.asmx - 401 Unauthorized error

Tags: asp.net, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm

CRM Portal is setup on "crmstaging" machine, on port 5555.

Following is the path of CRM Service:

```
http://crmstaging:5555/MSCrmServices/2007/CrmService.asmx
```

I am creating an ASP.NET Website on my dev machine "crmdev", and have added reference of the above service.
Now, I am trying to use various methods of this service to perform operations on my CRM entities, for that, I have written following code in button click of the page:

```
CrmAuthenticationToken token = new CrmAuthenticationToken();
        token.AuthenticationType = 0;
        token.OrganizationName = "MyCompany";

        CrmService service = new CrmService();
        service.CrmAuthenticationTokenValue = token;
        service.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username","password","domainname");
        //service.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

        string fetch1 = @"<fetch mapping=""logical"">
                <entity name=""account"">
                <all-attributes/>
                </entity>
                </fetch>";

        String result1 = service.Fetch(fetch1);
        txtBox1.Text = result1;
```

In above code, I have passed credentials of the user having access on CRM Staging machine.

While trying to execute this code, I get an error saying "401 Unauthorized".

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: I assume you have tried using the other defaultcredentials with same result?

Comment: yes, that's right. I first tried with that, and then tried with NetworkCredentials.. but same result both the times

Comment: And the credentials are correct? ;)

Comment: yes, they are. These are the same credentials that I use to log into that particular machine where CRM portal is hosted.

Comment: What happened on the error ??? How did you fix this. I am facing the same issue. My discovery service is returning the data correctly but CrmService is not... Can you help ?